# FloatingActionButton backgroundHint with alpha

Tags: android, floating-action-button

I've put a fab in my application.
I set the backgroundHint with opacity (#44FF0000).
But there is a little circle inside.

[fab image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ZyFo.png)

How can I remove this little circle?
This is my code

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/close"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
    android:layout_marginBottom="70dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="80dp"
    android:src="@drawable/phone"
    app:backgroundTint="#44FF0000" />
```

Thanks

Comment: You can't remove "this little circle". The shadow is drawn beneath the background. Use solid background with anything that drops a shadow. Case closed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't remove "this little circle". It's caused by the shadow being drawn beneath the background.

#### Alternative a)

Use solid background with anything that drops a shadow.

#### Alternative b)

Do not use shadow/elevation with translucent widgets. For FAB:

```
<...FloatingActionButton
    app:elevation="0dp"
    app:pressedTranslationZ="0dp"/>
```